# Error 42P01. not issue with braces

Tags: postgresql

Hello I am fairly new to PostgreSQL, I keep getting the following error code:

ERROR:  relation "contact" does not exist

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "contact" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01

Questions regarding this error code have been mentioned a lot on Stack Overflow and online, however I have tried checking for any braces that may change the letter case sensitivity of my code and was unable to find any.

This is how I've attempted to create the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE CONTACT (
   CONTACT_ID INTEGER,
   BUILDING_NO INTEGER,
   POSTCODE VARCHAR, 
   PHONE_NO INTEGER,
   EMAIL VARCHAR,
   CONSTRAINT PK_CONTACT_ID PRIMARY KEY (CONTACT_ID));
```

I would appreciate anyones help, and am sorry if this question may have been repeated, thank you guys :)

Comment: What code is getting the error.. I assume its not the create statement

Comment: It doesn't state which line. What I've copied is the entirety of the error code. And there doesn't appear to be any issues highlighted in my code. I could link a pastebin with the code in it if that helps, as its not particularly long.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/AL8VaPY1 if it helps

Comment: See my most recent answer/comment. It should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating your objects (tables) in the wrong order.
Create contact before you create tables that use contact as a foreign key-- or, create the foreign keys after you've created all your tables. The first table "student" is referencing contact, which has not been created yet.

EDIT:
Also, your phone number fields should not be integers, they should be text or varchar. If you're dead set on a numeric type, use bigint instead if integer.

Comment: I've changed the order and haven ow gotten the following error:ERROR:  integer out of range

********** Error **********

ERROR: integer out of range
SQL state: 22003

Comment: @EliasMalik Sounds like you need to enable statement logging, or (if using psql) run it with statement echo enabled, so you can see what statements are causing the errors.

Comment: See my updated comment. You are creating phone numbers as integers, which is a bad idea. Use text or varchar-- bigint if you are dead set on a numerical representation.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted you code and it worked for me.  Could it be something with your postgresql setup?

[image: Success]

EDITS BELOW

Alright so I'm going to add more to the solution

Like Joe Love Said, You have issues with the ordering. The proper ordering of your tables should be something like Contact, Status, Student, Company, Application and then the rest of the queries.

In your Application Table, the line

```
  CONSTRAINT FK_STATUS_ID FOREIGN KEY (STATUS_ID) REFERENCES STATUS (STATUS_ID),
```

Will give you an error.

Its because in the STATUS Table, you have set the ID as a VARCHAR and in the Application table, the Status is an INTEGER.

You still have some issues with the Application query referencing the Company Table as well.  If you fix them, you should be good.

Comment: I've tried a different computer however its not worked, it is under the same server though